# Get all managed files available for jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have stored configurations for some jobs in JSON format in the managed file section of Jenkins and it works as expected.
I want to expand this by changing these jobs to parametrized one, where all available managed files (not the global ones) could be selected from a combo box, but I have problems getting all available managed files.
Plugins like the configFileProvider are capable to get both the global ones and more workspace/namespace specific ones, so I thought there would be an easy way to achieve this.

Adding a more job-specific not global config file

[image: 1]

```
def files = org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.get().getConfigs()
```

works fine for the global ones, but I want to get workspace/namespace specific ones and thought it would go something like this

```
def files = org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.getConfigsInContext()
```

It would be amazing if somebody could point me in the right direction how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Workspace specific ones"? How are you creating workspace specific Config files? Maybe sharing a simplified version of your Pipeline would be helpful.

Comment: maybe workspace specific ones is plain wrong, but inside the namespace to not mix the config files in use with the ones from other projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following script

```
// name of the folde you want get configfiles from
def folderName = "Folder2" 
def folderItem = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder.class).find{ (it.name == folderName) }

// If you want to filter a specific configFile type, example Json configs here
def descriptor =  org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.json.JsonConfig.JsonConfigProvider.class 

def allConfigFiles = folderItem.getProperties().get(org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.folder.FolderConfigFileProperty.class).getConfigs();

def jonConfigFiles = folderItem.getProperties().get(org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.folder.FolderConfigFileProperty.class).getConfigs(descriptor);
            
echo "$allConfigFiles"
echo "$jonConfigFiles"
```

Comment: amazing!!! after a lot of approvals this method works a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any direct solution to achieve it as these managed files aren't stored as files in the disk.

My way to achieve it's running a script that parse the ${jenkins_home}/org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.xml  file and create the managed files in the  disk.

Having these files in the disk, you can use the "Filesystem List Parameter Plug-in" to list they in a job parameter.

This way you are

[image: job parameters]

[image: managed files]

[image: parameter setup]

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames=$(xmllint --xpath '//name/text()' GlobalConfigFiles.xml 2>/dev/null)

while read -r filename
do 

content=$(xmllint --xpath "//name[text()='$filename']/../content/text()" GlobalConfigFiles.xml 2>/dev/null)

if [[ "$filename" == *"xml"* ]]; then
    echo $content | sed -nr 's/&lt;/</gp' | sed -nr 's/&gt;/>/gp' > $filename
else
    echo $content > $filename
fi
done <<< $filenames
```

Comment: It's similar to the thing i want to achieve, but I'm looking for the workspace specific ones. I tried it with org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.configfiles.getConfigsInContext() but this didn't work (just testing in the Script-section at the moment)

Comment: I created a new job that create a file, the file path in the disk is /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/workspace_test_file.txt. So, you don't need the script and just point the parameter plugin to this path. Is that what you need? @Comodo3003